# How can I debug a custom implementation of IFixtureBuilder?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, nunit, nunit-3.0

We're using the NUnit 3 Test Adapter extension in Visual Studio 2015 to run our automation tests, and I'm trying to write my own implementation of IFixtureBuilder to generate more complex TestSuite trees, but can't figure out or find a way to debug my code when it's run as a part of NUnit's test discovery process, which is run every time the project is built. Is it possible to attach the VS debugger to NUnit in some way, or can I get some form of console output working at the very least?

Comment: Can you share some examples of your code? It helps everyone here to understand what is the problem and how to fix it

Comment: I could, but it wouldn't really be relevant to the question. I'm not looking for a fix to a problem I'm having, I'm asking if there is a way to debug NUnit's test generation process through Visual Studio. Basically, I'm looking for a way to set a debug breakpoint in my implementation of `IFixtureBuilder.BuildFrom()`.